# Handling multiple notifications to same Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have a service that broadcasts multiple notifications.  Each starts the same activity.  So if you have 3 notifications the first one opens the activity and works perfectly.  If I close the app and then click on the next notification it launches perfectly.  However if I keep the app open and click on my next notification nothing happens.

The app is 1 activity should I make another activity just to handle these notifications?

Notification Method:

```
private void sendNotification(ItemRunning item, int size) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Singleton.getAppContext(), MainActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("ALARM", item.getPrefName());
    bundle.putString("NAME", item.getDisplayName());
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Singleton.getAppContext(), Integer.valueOf(item.getPrefName()), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(Singleton.getAppContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(item.getDisplayName())
                    .setContentText("You have " + String.valueOf(size) + " results.");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) Singleton.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.valueOf(item.getPrefName()), mBuilder.build());

    Log.d(TAG, "sent alert " + String.valueOf(size) + "  id = " + item.getPrefName());
}
```

On New Intent:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent");
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null && bundle.getString("ALARM") != null) {
        initializeResults(bundle);
    } else {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:name=".Singleton"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MAINTHEME">
    <service android:name="service.MainService" />
    <receiver android:name="service.MainBroadcastReceiver" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MAINTHEME"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: override `onNewIntent`

Comment: added it nothing happens.  Its weird nothing even logs.

Comment: what is `launchMode` in the manifesto? `singleTop`?

Comment: yea  android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Comment: and `Activity#onNewIntent` is not called? weird...

Comment: Yea nothing is called I'll post my manifest and the onNewIntent

Comment: `<application>` has no `launchMode` attribute, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html